# How to select all records with multiple pages(pagination) in a datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using a DataTable that has multiple pages in it. I use Select All (jQuery based) functionality which works well to select all records in the current page being viewed. But the problem is

1. I am not able to select all records across different pages in a table
2. If I select record in one page and move to next page , records selected in first page are lost.

Can someone help me?

Comment: How do you select records?